# VBA: Convert number format / refresh cell

Tags: excel, vba, string, numbers

I have a problem that seams simple.

I have some cells that I can convert easily in Excel but I can't find a simple way to convert it in VBA.

The cells contains numbers in the format 35,00 and act like numbers (I can add them). But the aren't concidered as the same as number format 35.

If I click in the cell they will transform in the 35 format and therefore be considered as such.

Why does it matter?
Because of the code `Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(r.Offset(, -4), Sheets(4).Range("I3:I50"), 0) + 2, 9)` I'm using. The code works well if the format is 35, but doesn't work if the format is 35,00.

**Here's what I've tried to convert the 35,00 in 35.**

**What doesn't work in Excel:**

1. Changing format (for standard or number)
2. Copy/paste

**What works in Excel:**

1. Double-click in the cell and leave
2. Copy nothing and add it to the cell
3. Replace "," with ","

**What doesn't work in VBA:**

1)

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

2. 

```
Range("A3").Calculate
```

3. 

```
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

4. With Selection
   .NumberFormat = "0"
   .Value = .Value
   End With
5. 

```
Range("I1:I40") = Range("I1:I40").Value
```

6. 

```
Range("I2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("G:I").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
```

7. 

```
Columns("D:F").Select
Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

**What does work in VBA:**
1.

```
Selection = CLng(Selection)   '-- work only for 1 cell
```

In order to make it work, I would have do a For Each which seams a bit too much for what I need. Is there a way to convert a range at once?

It's weird that when I record a macro while fixing the issue in Excel (like replace "," by ","), the VBA code generated doesn't work.

Here's a sample file with the indomitable:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sSUo3tTORe6xLmj38EoMT0-SopNdr3Uk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112578955965682987037&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1):

vba:

***Edit:***

- *It appears that your system decimal symbol and the decimal symbol on the worksheet may be different*
- *In that case, you must first correct that*
- *It would be easiest to correct that at the time you import your data, as it is usually an option in the data import method*
- *Failing that, try this VBA macro:*

```
Option Explicit
Sub text2num()
    Dim range2Convert As Range, c As Range
    
Set range2Convert = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet9").Range("d129:d131")
    For Each c In range2Convert
        c.NumberFormat = "General"
        c.Value = WorksheetFunction.NumberValue(c.Value, ",", ".")
    Next c
End Sub
```

***Notes***
-*Change the `Range2Convert` argument as appropriate for your workbook*
-*Note that the VBA `NumberValue` function seems to require specifying both the decimal and the thousands separator.  I guessed at the thousands -- you may want to change that to match whatever it is for the incoming data, if not a dot.  No need if it isn't used*

Comment: Thanks Ron your your help,

Unfortunatly, I've try your code and it didn't work.

For all of my tests, the result is always that nothing changed. 

You can see the exact data in the sample file. The value looks like this: 35000,00

Comment: @OQC It looks like you have a `dot` set as the decimal in your Windows Regional Settings. If that is the case, then your entry is being interpreted as a text string. See my edited answer

Comment: Weirdly, I'm in comma separator. in Excel I can do : Replace "," by "," and it works.

Comment: @OQC It's not the separator, it's the decimal

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I've got so far:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

It converts 1 column at the time.